# How do I update a remote branch with changes from master

Tags: git, git-branch

I've done a fair bit of research/practices on rebasing and merging our remote branches but I am unable to find a solution that ultimately doesn't result in duplicate commits or a non-fast forward push of the remote branch. Here's what I'm trying to do.

We have two branches, `master` (tracking `origin/master`) and `hebe` (tracking `origin/hebe`). `hebe` was branched off of `master` appropriately a month ago. There are several developers working on both branches daily.

`master` is continuing to be maintained and has several bug fixes in common code that should be reflected/updated in the `hebe` branch. However none of the new code in `hebe` should make its way into `master`

I've tried:

```
git rebase master hebe
```

Which seemed from the log to be exactly what we wanted, `hebe` commits were on top of the latest `master`, however when I attempt to push `hebe` it resulted in a warning of a non-fast forward push of `origin/hebe`.

Or perhaps we are approaching this from the wrong direction and submodules would be the appropriate solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only rebase in very very very rare cases branches which are already pushed and shared with others since you rewrite the history and thus change the sha's of the commits. This results in your mentioned duplicate commits because a different sha means a different commit for git.
In your case it is better to merge the master with

```
$ git checkout hebe
$ git merge master
$ git push origin hebe
```

With this you merge all changes from master into `hebe` but nothing gets back to master and all shas stay the same. Merging will create an so called merge commit instead (if no fast-forward merge is possible).

Because it is so important and leads to so many confusion, I have to say this again on the end: Never rebase already shared branches unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing.

I deeply recommend reading the third chapter of the following (free online available) book http://git-scm.com/book to get a better understanding of how merging/rebasing works